# Changing Layout Parameters Inside a Fragment

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a button which will add new button next to it.
I am trying to do it inside my fragment but I am facing issue.
When I click that button my app crashes instantly and I am receiving this eror:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference.

Since I am new to programming it would be awesome if somebody could help me.
P.S. if this is not the recommended method I would to ask you if you can provide me a better method to add more buttons with one button.

My Java code:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2,container,false);
    dugme = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.dugme);
    dugme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LinearLayout linearni = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.linearni);
            Button newbtn = new Button(getActivity());
            newbtn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150,150));
            newbtn.setText("Yea");
            linearni.addView(newbtn);
        }
    });
    return v ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First of all, you have to check the id which you have passed in LinearLayout's findViewById method "linearni" with the id of LinearLayout declared in frag2.xml file.
- Second thing, you can find your LinearLayout outside the button's click event.

Like this

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag2,container,false);
 LinearLayout linearni = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.linearni);

dugme = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.dugme);
dugme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Button newbtn = new Button(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        newbtn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(150,150));
        newbtn.setText("Yea");
        linearni.addView(newbtn);
    }
});
return v;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this solution really helped me out !

Comment: I have changed Layout Parameters from 150x150 to 120x120 and my second button differs from my first. When I click to add more button it makes me small button. My first button is 120x120 but they are different.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access linear layout from the Button view that was passed from the onClick() listener. So Linear layout is null.

Change your click listener view param from v to view:

```
dugme.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) { // param now is view instead of v.
         // now you will access the real linear layout from main fragment view.
         LinearLayout linearni =(LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.linearni);
     }
});
```